# Asp.Net MVC core application Windows Authentication in IIS

Tags: iis, asp.net-core, windows-authentication

My Asp.Net Core mvc web application requires Anonymous Authentication.
below is the launchSettings.json code

```
 "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:61545/",
      "sslPort": 0
    }
  }
```

But after deploying,IIS Authentication settings are not changing based on launchSettings.json and it is changing based on authentication tag on  web.config, which will automatically generate on publish.I tried adding web.config manually in solution with proper authentication settings.But,i am not able to debug the solution.How can i debug the application without renaming/removing the web.config file?Or Please suggest any alternate solution for resolving this issue.

Comment: You'd better reveal more about "But IIS Authentication settings are changing based on web.config, which will automatically generate on publish." Or report to Microsoft via https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/post.html?space=8

Comment: What error did you get while debugging after adding web.config? For VS 2017, you are able to debug in IIS with creating new IIS profile. Refer [Enable development-time IIS support in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/development-time-iis-support?view=aspnetcore-2.2#enable-development-time-iis-support-in-visual-studio).